# DC Series Motor Starting Direction

Tags: dc-motor, speed

I have a 12V DC Series Motor - a car starting motor - for an experimental aircraft to pre-spin helecopter-type blades before takeoff. Usually, it works correctly but occasionally with power on, no rotation is developed. Turning it off and back on causes proper operation. Even more rarely, the motor develops rotation in the reverse direction. Turning it off and back on achieves normal operation. What can cause this? I'm thinking it's related to the commutator or brushes. The other possiblity being gremlins.

Second question on the same appplication. The motor develops enormous torque, spinning blades with a 25-foot diameter to 60 RPMs in three seconds. It's putting more stress on the airframe than I like. Is there a way to dial down or stage the acceleration of the motor to reduce the torque for the first few seconds?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's a brushed DC motor and not an AC motor packaged with a built-in inverter? These can also be called brushless DC motors.

Comment: I have not yet removed and disassembled to confirm brushes. It is an automobile-type starter motor with a Bendix gear that pops up when the motor spins. I have been told that starter motors are universally series motors for the high torque.

Comment: Is your motor able to spin at all if you provide it with 6 or 9 volts?  Your reverse spin or locked rotor problems may be a maintenance issue, but if your blades spin freely at all you should be able to start them spinning with a stick, pull away and then use the pre-starter.  In particular you don't want a locked rotor to persist for long.

Answer (score 0):

I can not envision a way for a series motor to fail in a way that would cause reverse operation. I suppose it could happen if the brush position is shifted or if one brush of a 4-pole motor is not making contact. A series motor is not a good choice to drive a propellor. The speed can be reduced by inserting series resistance. The resistors would need to be sized to dissipate a lot of power. An electronic speed controller would be better. The speed controller would need to be something like a fork truck controller. How much current does the motor draw at full speed?

Comment: Note that the motor is used for pre-spinning a rotor, which sounds a bit more like a gyrocopter than a helicopter, but who knows? At any rate, it seems unlikely that any sort of speed control is intended.

Comment: Speed control may not be intended, but that may be the best way to limit torque during acceleration.

Comment: Beast - You are right-it is a pre-rotator for a gyrocopter. The motor only has to run for 10 to 30 seconds max to spin up the blades at takeoff. After that airspeed drives the main rotor blades. That's not relevent to the problem so I left it out but the motor is not a drive motor in use for an extended time. (Just like an automobile starter)

Comment: Charles - speed control isn't normal in this application. Pilot/builders usually let it spin up but the power is greater than expected. What the motor is doing in three seconds I'd rather see in ten to fifteen seconds - I'd like to see the speed top out in 30 seconds.

Comment: Speed control is sometimes used only for acceleration control. It would definitely provide a soft start. The other alternative would be  to connect two or three resistors in series and short them out sequentially. That was a common DC motor control technique long ago.

Comment: Charles - If I hadn't seen the trailing edge going forward, I wouldn't believe the motor could spontaniously reverse either. I didn't let it contiue so I'm not sure it would have sustained a reverse direction. I haven't got a loop ammeter to check what it's drawing. The 12V battery is a motorcycle battery the cables (power and ground) are #10 wire and don't heat up but a small guage wire (not my installation) turned into a 10 inch fuse burning off insulation and melting open.

Comment: No. 10 wire will carry 40 amps all day long without getting too hot. It might carry twice that without heating up in 30 seconds. To properly select resistor values, you should determine both the initial and final current or otherwise get specifications for the starter motor.